# Hot tub deck construction

Tags: deck, construction

I have a deck that is 10’ off the bottom patio. Bands are 2x12. A single band against the house is lag bolted every other joist. The outer band is a double 2x12. Under the span of the hot tub (about 6.5 ft) I have 3 - 2x10x10 joists bolted together. The joists have bond timbers under them attached to the band. Will this amply hold the weight of the hot tub? (approx 5000 lb.) I do not want to put a post underneath in the center as it will block the walk way underneath. The outer band is supported about every 7-8 ft by 6x6.

Comment: Some locales require an engineering plan for elevated decks. Is that applicable to you?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no pro, but suspending 5000lbs above an occupied patio isn't something I'd recommend. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I've proposed an edit to your post in order to fix what I saw as various typos.  It would be great if you could check my proposed edit and either accept it, or reject it and otherwise [edit] the post yourself.

Comment: Can you draw a sketch with the layout of the timbers?  I can't really visualize what is going on.  Somebody might be able to say from that - but I suspect you really need a structural engineer to approve the plans.  Supporting more than two tons is not trivial.